# Django don't generate primary_key

Tags: django, django-models

I write the migration manually to quickly add to the new environment. When I try to create a new object of the Operator model I get an error about an empty id. I tried to set `managed = False` in meta and fake `Operator` model but none of this brought results. What's wrong with my code?

My model:

```
class Operator(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    class Meta:
        db_table = '"mts_market"."operator"'
        managed = False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My migration:

```
from django.db import migrations


def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    product = apps.get_model("landings", "Product")
    merchant = apps.get_model("landings", "Merchant")
    partner = apps.get_model("landings", "Partner")
    operator = apps.get_model("landings", "Operator")
    tariff = apps.get_model("landings", "Tariff")
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    partner = partner.objects.using(db_alias).get(name="binding")
    merchant = merchant.objects.using(db_alias).get(name="dc")
    operator.objects.using(db_alias).bulk_create([
        operator(name="test")
    ])
    operator = operator.objects.using(db_alias).get(name="test")
    product.objects.using(db_alias).bulk_create([
        product(name="mirrorcheck", merchant=merchant,
                mnp_service_name_card="test",
                partner=partner,
                operator=operator,
                sub_service_name_card="test",
                has_many_subs=True, category='retail',
    ])
    product = product.objects.using(db_alias).get(name="mirrorcheck",
                                                  partner=partner.id, merchant=merchant.id, operator=operator.id)
    tariff.objects.using(db_alias).bulk_create([
        tariff(name='card_subscription', value=100,
        product=product, mnp_instance_details={},
               sub_instance_details={"amount": 29900},
               )
    ])
    partner = partner.objects.using(db_alias).get(name="upfront")
    product.objects.using(db_alias).bulk_create([
        product(name="mirrorcheck", merchant=merchant,
                mnp_service_name_card="test",
                partner=partner,
                operator=operator,
                sub_service_name_card="zenit_bank_test",
                has_many_subs=True, category='retail',
    ])
    product = product.objects.using(db_alias).get(name="mirrorcheck",
                                                  partner=partner.id, merchant=merchant.id, operator=operator.id)
    tariff.objects.using(db_alias).bulk_create([
        tariff(name='card_subscription', value=29900,
               product=product, mnp_instance_details={},
               sub_instance_details={"amount": 29900},
               )
    ])


def reverse_func(apps, schema_editor):
    operator = apps.get_model("landings", "Operator")
    product = apps.get_model("landings", "Product")
    tariff = apps.get_model("landings", "Tariff")
    partner = apps.get_model("landings", "Partner")
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    partner = partner.objects.using(db_alias).get(name="binding")
    operator = operator.objects.using(db_alias).get(name="test")
    product = product.objects.using(db_alias).get(name="mirrorcheck", operator=operator.id, partner=partner.id)
    tariff.objects.using(db_alias).get(name="card_subscription", product=product.id).delete()
    product.delete()
    partner = partner.objects.using(db_alias).get(name="upfront")
    product = product.objects.using(db_alias).get(name="mirrorcheck", operator=operator.id, partner=partner.id)
    tariff.objects.using(db_alias).get(name="card_subscription", product=product.id).delete()
    product.delete()
    operator.delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [('landings', '0026_product_operator')]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(forwards_func, reverse_func),
    ]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: ОШИБКА:  нулевое значение в столбце "id" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL
DETAIL:  Ошибочная строка содержит (null, test).
```

Comment: `id` is the default model PK so you don't need to define it explicitly. If you still want to define it yourself, make it AutoField instead of IntegerField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is the default model PK so you don't need to define it explicitly.

If you still want to define it yourself, make it [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) instead of `IntegerField`.